# Pandas: Convert Column to timedelta64

Tags: python, pandas, timedelta

I try to read a CSV file as pandas data frame. Beside column names, I get the expected dtype. My approach is:

1. reading the CSV with inferring column types (as I want to be able
   to catch issues)
2. reading the expected column types
3. iterating over the columns and try to convert them with `'astype'`

Now, I have timedeltas in nanoseconds. They are read in as float64 and can contain missing values. `'astype'` fails with the following message:

```
ValueError: Cannot convert non-finite values (NA or inf) to integer
```

This little script can reproduce my issue. The method `'to_timedelta'` works perfekt on my data while the conversion give the error.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

timedeltas  = [200800700,30020010030,np.NaN]
data = {'timedelta': timedeltas}

pd.to_timedelta(timedeltas)

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

df.dtypes

df['timedelta'].astype('timedelta64[ns]')
```

Can anybody help to fix this issue? Is there any other save representation than nanoseconds which would work with `'astype'`?

Comment: you should try `pd.to_timedelta(timedelta, errors='coerce')`. https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_timedelta.html

Comment: the `to_timedelta` works well. But I fail to convert the column of the dataframe. Would I have to use `to_timedelta` instead of `astype` somehow? if yes, how?

Comment: just use `df['timedelta'] = pd.to_timedelta(df['timedelta'])`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to [MrFuppes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61386299/pandas-convert-column-to-timedelta64?noredirect=1#comment108713254_61386299).

It's not possible to use `astype()` but `to_timedelta` works. Thank you!

```
df['timedelta'] = pd.to_timedelta(df['timedelta'])
```